# "Convoluted" sum convergence: $\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i \sum_{k=0}^{n-i} b_k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Suppose $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_j =a$, $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} b_j =b$. Is it true (or under what conditions is it true) that:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n} \left( a_i \sum_{k=0}^{n-i} b_k \right) = ab \ ? \tag{1}$$

This arose in one of my earlier questions ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380563/check-my-answer-a-slight-modification-to-the-hat-check-problem/380708?noredirect=1#380708)) and at first I thought it was sort of obvious - expanding it out, but now I'm confused again and I want to make this rigorous. I've looked into Cauchy's product formula since it rang a bell but I can't really make my sum look like anything similar to it. One (perhaps trivial) thing I noticed about this is the symmetry:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} \left( a_i \sum_{k=0}^{n-i} b_k \right) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \left( a_k \sum_{k=0}^{n-i} b_i \right)$$

But doesn't get me anywhere. What I'm looking for is a rigorous proof of $(1)$, and I can't make any headway on that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
 $$\sum_{i=0}^{n} \left( a_i \sum_{k=0}^{n-i} b_k \right) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \left( a_k \sum_{k=0}^{n-i} b_i \right)=\sum _{i+k\le n}a_ib_k$$

What you are considering is exactly the Cauchy's product formula.

Comment: Thanks! I wrote the sum explicitly in a table and indeed, summing diagonally gives the Cauchy product formula. I guess I was in the right ballpark :)

Comment: @DepeHb: It's not quite clear to me from your comment and the question whether you're aware that this answer implies that your limit formula doesn't hold in general. (See my answer.)

Comment: I am aware of the conditions for the Cauchy product to be convergent, it's just that in my particular problem both the series were absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general. As Ma Ming has pointed out, your sum is a partial sum of the Cauchy product of the two sequences. These partial sums can be shown to converge to $ab$ if at least one of the series converges absolutely. Generally the partial sums of the Cauchy product need not converge; a counterexample is afforded by $a_n=b_n=(-1)^n/\sqrt{n+1}$, both of which yield conditionally convergent series, whereas the partial sums of the Cauchy product do not converge.

See also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Convergence_and_Mertens.27_theorem).